# How to convert a JPEG to GeoTiff using FME?

Tags: raster, fme-form

I want  to convert JPEG to Geotiff in FME.

I use the following workspace
**JPEG reader** -> **RasterExtractor** -> **CoordinateSystemSetter** -> **RasterGeoreferencer** (parameter : extents) -> **Reprojector** -> **GEOTIFF** writer.

The transformation fails at the RasterGeoreferencer with error

*Invalid coordinates.  The four coordinates must form a rectangle, which can be rotated
RasterGeoreferencer: A fatal error has occurred. Check the logfile above for details*

Any suggestions?

Comment: EPSG:2100 to EPSG:3857

Comment: **If** you're entering EPSG:2100 into `RasterGeoreferencer` and `CoordinateSystemSetter`, but want the output in EPSG:3857, then you will need the Reprojector part to do that (ignore that part of my reply).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok. I think what's going on is that you have the wrong parameters set in RasterGeoreferencer. The below image is WRONG:

[image: wrong]

What's going on there (and what I guess you're doing) is that I've not specified a square for the coordinates, they're going to make some weird shape. This gives me the same error you're getting.

---

What you need to do is enter correct, square/rectangular coordinates. So if you had a raster like this:
[image: grid]

I'd enter co-ordinates like this:

[image: Correct]

Although that does turn it upside down which is possibly undesirable, but that's just trial and error. :-) Either way, it is projected now!

---

Also: I don't think you need the `RasterExtractor` (mine works fine without it) unless you want to put the raster into a specific attribute (which you don't).

Nor do you need the `Reprojector` because what that does is change from one coordinate system to another, but if you've set it with `CoordinateSystemSetter` and `RasterGeoreferencer`, then its already set.

Comment: fyi In FME2013 we've made this transformer a bit more lenient, so that if the numbers aren't quite right, it will still pass. It's only a "bit" lenient; the data will still need to be approximately square of course.

Comment: I was looking for a way to take JPG (no geo reference) and convert it to LL84. This helped a lot. All I needed was to use the coordinatesetter and the rastergeoreferences. Thank you.